# Combining two lists of data into one Vuetify autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have two sets of data, both in list [] format, the first list is the prefixes, second is the units.

What I need the autocomplete to do is start on prefixes, but once a prefix is selected from the autocomplete, I need the autocomplete to re-populate with the data from units.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

This is what I have tried...

```
<template>
      <v-autocomplete
            label="Select Unit"
            :items="currentItems"
            v-model="selectedUnit"
      />
</template>
```

```
<script>
import { ref, computed, watch } from 'vue';
const props = defineProps(['prefixes', 'units']);
const prefixes = computed(() => props.prefixes);
const units = computed(() => props.units);
var currentItems = ref(prefixes.value);

watch(selectedUnit, (newVal, oldVal) => {
  if (prefixes.value.includes(newVal)) {
    currentItems.value = units;
    console.log(oldVal);
  } else {
    currentItems.value = prefixes;
  }
});
</script>
```

What's happening is the autocomplete populates initially with the correct data (prefixes), but it then hits an error once you select an item.

I believe the error below is from the current value of the autocomplete (ronna) not being in the new data set for the autocomplete, since I reassigned it to units instead of prefixes. Can anyone confirm?

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:40 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/core 
  at <VAutocomplete label="Select Unit" items=Ref< (3260) ['s', 'second', 'c_SI', 'c', 'm', 'meter', 'metre', 'h_SI', 'h', 'kg', 'kilogram', 'k_SI', 'boltzmann', 'k', 'K', 'kelvin', 'e_SI', 'e', 'A', 'ampere', 'amp', 'avogadro', 'N_A', 'mol', 'mole', 'cd', 'candela', 'radian', 'sr', 'steradian', 'B', 'byte', 'bit', 'one', 'two', 'double', 'couple', 'three', 'triple', 'four', 'quadruple', 'five', 'quintuple', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety', 'hundred', 'thousand', 'million', 'shortbillion', 'shorttrillion', 'shortquadrillion', 'shortquintillion', 'shortsextillion', 'shortseptillion', 'shortoctillion', 'shortnonillion', 'shortnoventillion', 'shortdecillion', 'shortundecillion', 'shortduodecillion', 'shorttredecillion', 'shortquattuordecillion', 'shortquindecillion', 'shortsexdecillion', 'shortseptendecillion', 'shortoctodecillion', 'shortnovemdecillion', 'shortvigintillion', 'centillion', 'googol', 'longbillion', 'longtrillion', 'longquadrillion', 'longquintillion', 'longsextillion', 'longseptillion', 'longoctillion', 'longnonillion', 'longnoventillion', 'longdecillion', …] > modelValue="ronna"  ... > 
  at <BaseTransition appear=false persisted=false mode=undefined  ... > 
  at <Transition name="v-window-x-transition" onBeforeEnter=fn<onBeforeTransition> onAfterEnter=fn<onAfterTransition>  ... > 
  at <MaybeTransition transition= {name: 'v-window-x-transition', onBeforeEnter: ƒ, onAfterEnter: ƒ, onEnterCancelled: ƒ, onBeforeLeave: ƒ, …} > 
  at <VWindowItem key="basic" value="basic" > 
  at <VWindow modelValue="basic" onUpdate:modelValue=fn > 
  at <VCardText> 
  at <VCard> 
  at <VDefaultsProvider root=true > 
  at <BaseTransition onAfterLeave=fn<onAfterLeave> appear=true persisted=true  ... > 
  at <Transition name="dialog-transition" appear=true persisted=true  ... > 
  at <VDialogTransition appear=true persisted=true target=undefined  ... > 
  at <MaybeTransition appear=true persisted=true transition= {component: {…}}  ... > 
  at <VOverlay ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {…} > class="v-dialog" maxWidth="600px"  ... > 
  at <VDialog modelValue=true onUpdate:modelValue=fn persistent=""  ... > 
  at <EditGaugeModal key=0 show=true success=false  ... > 
  at <GaugeEditorPage onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {__v_skip: true} > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <VMain class="d-flex" > 
  at <VApp> 
  at <App>
```

This error is in red after the above warning:

```
createForOfIteratorHelper.js:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
    at _createForOfIteratorHelper (createForOfIteratorHelper.js:26:1)
    at transformItems (items.ts:83:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.eval [as fn] (items.ts:93:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:187:1)
    at get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1150:1)
    at unref (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1056:1)
    at eval (filter.ts:146:1)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:157:1)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:166:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.getter [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:1732:1)
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: shouldn't it be:
currentItems.value = units.value; 
and:
currentItems.value = prefixes.value;
because now you are just assigning the computed properties instead of the resulting values of the computed.